# Heroku running a node module server

Tags: node.js, heroku, server

I am trying to create a node app that runs a module called noodlejs. This starts its own server running on port 8888 (on my local version). I have pushed the changes to heroku and no errors are caused. However how do I now access the noodlejs server on port 8888? Is this possible or does it need to run on another port?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the details of Heroku, but I think it provides an environment variable that specifies the port your server is supposed to run on so you need to fetch the info and have your server listen to that port.  You can then connection to your domain on the normal port 80 and Heroku will port-forward to your actual server port.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run the app on port 8888 or any other port for that matter on Heroku. You can only choose between 80 or 443. And to do that, you use `process.env.PORT` environment variable that Heroku exposes.